# How to write program that is agnostic of the framework

Tags: c++, qt

I recently read an OOP book (Robert Martin I think) that emphasized using a core object that calls interfaces of the things it uses.  The point here is that the peripheral objects depend on the core rather than the other way around.  This allows better modularity, flexibility, distribution of binaries, build time, etc.  Supposedly you can also allow your program to be independent of any particular framework, eg GUI, database, etc.  But I'm having a hard time separating the framework from the core.

For example the Qt framework provides class `QTreeView`; some functions take instances of `QAbstractItemModel`.
It's conceivable I find or write a different model/view I want to use that is not part of the Qt world, or use some immediate-mode api for the graphics part, etc.

So how do I write my core to be agnostic of Qt entirely?
Do I make up an `ITreeView` with similar functions as `QTreeView`, with similar-sounding non-Qt arguments and then delegate to a real `QTreeView` instance after converting all arguments to real Qt types?  It seems silly to recreate so much of the framework just to make it generic.

Or in the real world are people fully absorbed into Qt and it's not realistic to keep it separated?

Comment: Yes, in principle you create wrappers around the concrete framework classes. Note that the "core" often needs only limited functionality, e.g. you need to iterate through a container but you are not interested in the particular implementation, so that the wrapper does not need to emulate *all* of the tree.

Comment: With respect to the GUI: I suppose you program the GUI part in whichever framework you use, but couple it only loosely with the "core" (which passes and receives data but does not manipulate the GUI directly and does not see GUI classes). Ideally the GUI part is a sort of a "plug-in" module.

Comment: I agree with Peter, if you are concerned about the Qt dependency, I'd keep the core Qt-free, not introduce another abstraction layer in the UI code, which leads to overengineered bloat, IMHO.

Comment: This depends entirely on what the "core" does. But most GUI frameworks assume they are running the show, because they need an event loop which handles the GUI stuff. So your "core" should then be something which is called by the GUI (for example, user makes a mouse click to expose a new branch of your tree view), not the other way around, not "a core object that calls interfaces", or things will get complex and tedious.

Comment: I'm largely able to separate the gui part.  What is troubling me is that in trying to keep classes doing only one thing, I now have some classes that deal with a `qsqldatabase`, and then that gets involved with a `qsqltablemodel`, which then gets passed to a `qtableview`.  So if the core is serving as the conduit for these objects, it either has to deal with `std::any`, `void *`, or get itself dirty with 'QSqlTableModels', etc.  But turning everything into a `std::any` or `void *` seems incorrect...